# How can I add a method to Eigen3 library for solving an equation system

Tags: eigen3

I am new with Eigen3 and I think it is very good C++ implementation for linear algebra. I would like to add some extra methods to the standard Matrix class for simplifying the use, for instance, for solving an equations system we can make (from the Eigen web):

```
Matrix3f A;
Vector3f b;
A << 1,2,3,  4,5,6,  7,8,10;
b << 3, 3, 4;
cout << "Here is the matrix A:\n" << A << endl;
cout << "Here is the vector b:\n" << b << endl;
Vector3f x = A.colPivHouseholderQr().solve(b);
cout << "The solution is:\n" << x << endl;
```

And it solve the equations system:
Here is the matrix A:

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8 10
```

Here is the vector b:

```
3
3
4
```

The solution is:

```
-2
 1
 1
```

It is ok. I would like to create a new method named solveSystem() to the
Matrix class. For that I have discovered that it can be done creating an
extra header with the new methods and then use the define #define EIGEN_MATRIXBASE_PLUGIN "MatrixBaseAddons.h". Then I try to code this as:

```
template<typename OtherDerived>
MatrixBase<Derived> solveQr(const Eigen::MatrixBase<OtherDerived>& b)
{
    MatrixXd solution = this->colPivHouseholderQr().solve(b);
    return solution;
}
```

I have a lot of compilation errors in multiple templates. I suposse it is because I am doing something wrong. Anyone knows how pass properly other matrices and return a matrix and how to program this simple method?
Thanks in advance.
Pedro

Comment: Can you be more specific regarding your errors and setup? Using Eigen 3.3.1 and VS2015, I got no compilation errors when copying your example.

Comment: Hello I got the following error: error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>' to 'Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>'

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your plugin is that it tries to convert a `MatrixXd` to a `MatrixBase<Matrix3f>` (if you apply it to the problem at the top).
Generally, you can't create pure `MatrixBase<...>` classes (these are just to be used as base classes). Also, you can't implicitly convert a double matrix to a float matrix.

To solve your problem, something like this should work:

```
template<typename OtherDerived>
Matrix<Scalar, RowsAtCompileTime, OtherDerived::ColsAtCompileTime> solveQr(const MatrixBase<OtherDerived>& b)
{
    return this->colPivHouseholderQr().solve(b);
}
```

If you want to mix real matrices and complex `b`, you need to write something more sophisticated.